# callback of react setState is not working in my case

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Anything wrong with this line of code?

```
increase = () => {
    this.setState((prevState,props) => this.state.index = prevState.index + 1)
  }
```

Won't work compared to this

```
this.setState({ index: this.state.index + 1 })
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The function given to `setState` must return an object, that will be "merged" with your current state. You are not returning an object.

You need to do something like this:

```
increase = () => {
  this.setState((prevState,props) => ({
    index: prevState.index + 1
  }))
}
```

Comment: sorry, missed that.